# How to screen out non-virtual machine ip address

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I'm using the code below
local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
, but i find that the default address is an ip of vmware,which is not what i want.
As we know, we can enumerate the ip addresses by hostinfo->h_addr_list, but how to screen out the non-virtual-machine ip addresses?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. If what you mean is distinguish a VM IP address from a non-VM IP address, then there's no way to do so having only the IP address.

Comment: It is also possible to configure VMWare to not use virtual IPs at all, it can share the host's physical IPs instead.

Answer (score 0):

i've solved this problem by enumerate network adapters by GetAdaptersInfo/getifaddrs